# Fatal error: Class NativeSessionTokenStorage not found in Silex

Tags: php, class, silex

> Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\NativeSessionTokenStorage' not found in

I've just installed FormServiceProvider to my Silex application. But when I try to load the page, the error above appears. I've looked into my files, and I've found the Symfony folder, but there's no Component folder in it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall security CSRF using

```
composer require symfony/security-csrf
```